# Deploying django to CentOS using gunicorn and supervisord start additional process django-admin.py

Tags: python, django, centos6, gunicorn, supervisord

I deploy django project to CentOS for a first time, I have been used before Ubuntu for a few applications. 
When I start the application with supervisord there is few gunicorn process that starts and one celery process and I am OK with It. But there is few more processes that start (num of gunicorn processes + num of celery processes) as django-admin.py.

```
ps -e | grep guni
41570 ?        00:00:01 gunicorn
41579 ?        00:00:01 gunicorn
41580 ?        00:00:01 gunicorn
41582 ?        00:00:01 gunicorn

ps -e | grep celery
41635 ?        00:00:00 celery.sh

ps -e | grep django
41641 ?        00:00:03 django-admin.py
41646 ?        00:00:00 django-admin.py
41647 ?        00:00:00 django-admin.py
41648 ?        00:00:00 django-admin.py
41649 ?        00:00:00 django-admin.py
41650 ?        00:00:00 django-admin.py
```

Any idea why django-admin.py processes start ?

Comment: Can you please provide all supervisor files?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found out that these processes are actually celery processes only their name does not match.